# How to insert data inside a polygon column in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

How can i insert a geo co-ordinates data inside a polygon field in mysql , Here is a sample query am using for test

```
INSERT INTO `zones` (`polygon`) VALUES 
('POLYGON(34.44 33.56,32.22 31.34,30.23 26.33,34.44 33.56)')
```

I keep getting this error when i try to submit the query **#1416 - Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the string to proper statial typ in your case `ST_GeomFromText`

```
CREATE TABLE zones (`polygon` GEOMETRY);
```

```
INSERT INTO `zones` (`polygon`) VALUES 
(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((34.44 33.56,32.22 31.34,30.23 26.33,34.44 33.56))'))
```

```
SELECT * FROM zones
```

| polygon |
| --- |
| 0000000001030000000100000004000000b81e85eb5138414048e17a14aec740405c8fc2f5281c4040d7a3703d0a573f407b14ae47e13a3e4014ae47e17a543a40b81e85eb5138414048e17a14aec74040 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0eqMt06I)

Comment: any idea why this is not working when using SET like this query `"INSERT INTO " . $this->tb_zone . " SET id = '78231', cord = 'ST_GeomFromText(\'POLYGON((34.44 33.56,32.22 31.34,30.23 26.3,34.44 33.56))\')' "`

Comment: yes you have a single quote before ST_GeomFromText that doesn't belong there https://dbfiddle.uk/9HrnDstD why not use the traditional way with values